# Varying Likert Scale Categories

Tags: likert, cronbachs-alpha

I hope that someone can help me with this question.

I created a questionnaire that has different scales for each of the questions under one construct. Each of the questions still have a 5 point scale but the variable associated with the numbers 1 - 5 vary per question, e.g. Q1: agree - disagree, Q2: low - high, etc.

In this situation, is it possible to run a Cronbach's alpha test, or are there any other tests that can be used for reliability?

Thanks
Kas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cronbach's alpha just cares about the numbers, not the labels associated with them.  So, you can run it.  But there are at least two issues:

1. You have ordinal data. You may want to use a measure that accounts for that (however, many people do ignore this problem in practice).  Some research on this subject is in [Gaderman, Guhn and Zumbo (2012)](http://pareonline.net/pdf/v17n3.pdf) . They recommend using polychoric correlations in the calculation of alpha for ordinal data.
2. As usual, the categories have to "line up". That is, a higher score on one should be associated with a higher score on the others.